# brasero: Please replace the disc with a supported CD or DVD

Tags: debian, dvd, burning

Is there a way to burn a DVD on a Debian/stable system. Here is what brasero is telling me when trying to burn a iso file:

[image]

For information:

```
% file 7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso 
7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD' (bootable)
```

and

```
% cdrskin --devices                                                                                      
cdrskin 1.5.0 : limited cdrecord compatibility wrapper for libburn
cdrskin: scanning for devices ...
cdrskin: ... scanning for devices done
cdrskin: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  dev='/dev/sr0'  rwrw-- :  'HL-DT-ST'  'DVD+-RW GH82N'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
% dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/dvd
INQUIRY:                [HL-DT-ST][DVD+-RW GH82N   ][A101]
GET [CURRENT] CONFIGURATION:
 Mounted Media:         2Bh, DVD+R Double Layer
 Media ID:              MBIPG101/R10
 Current Write Speed:   8.0x1385=11080KB/s
 Write Speed #0:        8.0x1385=11080KB/s
 Write Speed #1:        6.0x1385=8310KB/s
 Write Speed #2:        4.0x1385=5540KB/s
 Write Speed #3:        2.4x1385=3324KB/s
GET [CURRENT] PERFORMANCE:
 Write Performance:     4.0x1385=5540KB/s@[0 -> 196607]
                        6.0x1385=8310KB/s@[196608 -> 385023]
                        8.0x1385=11079KB/s@[385024 -> 3788799]
                        6.0x1385=8310KB/s@[3788800 -> 3977215]
                        4.0x1385=5540KB/s@[3977216 -> 4173823]
 Speed Descriptor#0:    02/4173823 R@12.0x1385=16629KB/s W@8.0x1385=11080KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#1:    02/4173823 R@12.0x1385=16629KB/s W@6.0x1385=8310KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#2:    02/4173823 R@12.0x1385=16629KB/s W@4.0x1385=5540KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#3:    02/4173823 R@12.0x1385=16629KB/s W@2.4x1385=3324KB/s
READ DVD STRUCTURE[#0h]:
 Media Book Type:       00h, DVD-ROM book [revision 0]
 Legacy lead-out at:    2086912*2KB=4273995776
DVD+R DOUBLE LAYER BOUNDARY INFORMATION:
 L0 Data Zone Capacity: 2086912*2KB, can still be set
READ DISC INFORMATION:
 Disc status:           blank
 Number of Sessions:    1
 State of Last Session: empty
 "Next" Track:          1
 Number of Tracks:      1
READ TRACK INFORMATION[#1]:
 Track State:           blank
 Track Start Address:   0*2KB
 Next Writable Address: 0*2KB
 Free Blocks:           4173824*2KB
 Track Size:            4173824*2KB
 ROM Compatibility LBA: 266240
READ CAPACITY:          0*2048=0
```

I did read:

- https://wiki.debian.org/BurnCd#Burn_the_image_file_to_CD.2C_DVD.2C_or_BD

So if I now try from the command line:

```
% cdrskin -dummy 7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso 
cdrskin 1.5.0 : limited cdrecord compatibility wrapper for libburn
cdrskin: scanning for devices ...
cdrskin: ... scanning for devices done
cdrskin: beginning to burn disc
cdrskin: NOTE : -dummy mode will prevent actual writing
cdrskin: SORRY : Drive offers no suitable write mode with this job
cdrskin: Reason: SAO: simulation of write job not supported by drive and media, 
cdrskin: Media : blank DVD+R/DL
cdrskin: FATAL : burning failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried growisofs and it worked just fine, would be nice to know what was the whole issue here.

```
% growisofs  -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso        
Executing 'builtin_dd if=7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
:-? more than 50% of space will be *wasted*!
/dev/sr0: splitting layers at 773168 blocks
/dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 8.2x1352KBps.
    7766016/3166840832 ( 0.2%) @1.7x, remaining 33:53 RBU 100.0% UBU   2.9%
   26214400/3166840832 ( 0.8%) @4.0x, remaining 17:58 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
   44695552/3166840832 ( 1.4%) @4.0x, remaining 13:58 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
   63143936/3166840832 ( 2.0%) @4.0x, remaining 12:17 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
   81625088/3166840832 ( 2.6%) @4.0x, remaining 11:58 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  100073472/3166840832 ( 3.2%) @4.0x, remaining 11:14 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  118554624/3166840832 ( 3.7%) @4.0x, remaining 10:42 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  137003008/3166840832 ( 4.3%) @4.0x, remaining 10:41 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  155484160/3166840832 ( 4.9%) @4.0x, remaining 10:19 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  173932544/3166840832 ( 5.5%) @4.0x, remaining 10:02 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  192413696/3166840832 ( 6.1%) @4.0x, remaining 10:02 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  210862080/3166840832 ( 6.7%) @4.0x, remaining 9:48 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  229343232/3166840832 ( 7.2%) @4.0x, remaining 9:36 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  247791616/3166840832 ( 7.8%) @4.0x, remaining 9:37 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  266272768/3166840832 ( 8.4%) @4.0x, remaining 9:26 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  284753920/3166840832 ( 9.0%) @4.0x, remaining 9:16 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  303202304/3166840832 ( 9.6%) @4.0x, remaining 9:17 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  321683456/3166840832 (10.2%) @4.0x, remaining 9:08 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  340164608/3166840832 (10.7%) @4.0x, remaining 9:00 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  358612992/3166840832 (11.3%) @4.0x, remaining 9:00 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  377094144/3166840832 (11.9%) @4.0x, remaining 8:52 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  395575296/3166840832 (12.5%) @4.0x, remaining 8:45 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  404291584/3166840832 (12.8%) @1.9x, remaining 8:59 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  425459712/3166840832 (13.4%) @4.6x, remaining 8:48 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  453345280/3166840832 (14.3%) @6.0x, remaining 8:28 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  481230848/3166840832 (15.2%) @6.0x, remaining 8:16 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  509149184/3166840832 (16.1%) @6.0x, remaining 8:00 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  537034752/3166840832 (17.0%) @6.0x, remaining 7:45 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  564953088/3166840832 (17.8%) @6.0x, remaining 7:35 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  592871424/3166840832 (18.7%) @6.0x, remaining 7:22 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  620756992/3166840832 (19.6%) @6.0x, remaining 7:10 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  648708096/3166840832 (20.5%) @6.1x, remaining 7:03 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  676626432/3166840832 (21.4%) @6.0x, remaining 6:52 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  704544768/3166840832 (22.2%) @6.0x, remaining 6:41 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  732463104/3166840832 (23.1%) @6.0x, remaining 6:35 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  760414208/3166840832 (24.0%) @6.1x, remaining 6:26 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  788332544/3166840832 (24.9%) @6.0x, remaining 6:17 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  790921216/3166840832 (25.0%) @0.6x, remaining 6:27 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  827949056/3166840832 (26.1%) @8.0x, remaining 6:12 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
  864944128/3166840832 (27.3%) @8.0x, remaining 5:59 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  901971968/3166840832 (28.5%) @8.0x, remaining 5:49 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
  939032576/3166840832 (29.7%) @8.0x, remaining 5:36 RBU  99.8% UBU 100.0%
  976060416/3166840832 (30.8%) @8.0x, remaining 5:25 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 1013088256/3166840832 (32.0%) @8.0x, remaining 5:16 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1050116096/3166840832 (33.2%) @8.0x, remaining 5:06 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1078919168/3166840832 (34.1%) @6.2x, remaining 4:59 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1115947008/3166840832 (35.2%) @8.0x, remaining 4:52 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1152974848/3166840832 (36.4%) @8.0x, remaining 4:42 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1190002688/3166840832 (37.6%) @8.0x, remaining 4:34 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1227030528/3166840832 (38.7%) @8.0x, remaining 4:27 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1264058368/3166840832 (39.9%) @8.0x, remaining 4:18 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1301118976/3166840832 (41.1%) @8.0x, remaining 4:10 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1338146816/3166840832 (42.3%) @8.0x, remaining 4:04 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1375207424/3166840832 (43.4%) @8.0x, remaining 3:57 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1412235264/3166840832 (44.6%) @8.0x, remaining 3:49 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1449295872/3166840832 (45.8%) @8.0x, remaining 3:43 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1478361088/3166840832 (46.7%) @6.3x, remaining 3:39 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1515388928/3166840832 (47.9%) @8.0x, remaining 3:32 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1552416768/3166840832 (49.0%) @8.0x, remaining 3:26 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1584562176/3166840832 (50.0%) @7.0x, remaining 3:21 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1584562176/3166840832 (50.0%) @0.0x, remaining 3:24 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1609433088/3166840832 (50.8%) @5.4x, remaining 3:22 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1646460928/3166840832 (52.0%) @8.0x, remaining 3:15 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 1683456000/3166840832 (53.2%) @8.0x, remaining 3:09 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1720451072/3166840832 (54.3%) @8.0x, remaining 3:04 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1757446144/3166840832 (55.5%) @8.0x, remaining 2:58 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1794441216/3166840832 (56.7%) @8.0x, remaining 2:52 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1831436288/3166840832 (57.8%) @8.0x, remaining 2:46 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1868431360/3166840832 (59.0%) @8.0x, remaining 2:41 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1905426432/3166840832 (60.2%) @8.0x, remaining 2:35 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1942388736/3166840832 (61.3%) @8.0x, remaining 2:30 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 1979383808/3166840832 (62.5%) @8.0x, remaining 2:25 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2016346112/3166840832 (63.7%) @8.0x, remaining 2:19 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2053308416/3166840832 (64.8%) @8.0x, remaining 2:15 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2090270720/3166840832 (66.0%) @8.0x, remaining 2:09 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2127265792/3166840832 (67.2%) @8.0x, remaining 2:04 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2164228096/3166840832 (68.3%) @8.0x, remaining 1:59 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2201157632/3166840832 (69.5%) @8.0x, remaining 1:54 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2238119936/3166840832 (70.7%) @8.0x, remaining 1:49 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2275049472/3166840832 (71.8%) @8.0x, remaining 1:45 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2311979008/3166840832 (73.0%) @8.0x, remaining 1:40 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2348941312/3166840832 (74.2%) @8.0x, remaining 1:35 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2380005376/3166840832 (75.2%) @6.7x, remaining 1:32 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2392719360/3166840832 (75.6%) @2.8x, remaining 1:31 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2420572160/3166840832 (76.4%) @6.0x, remaining 1:27 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2448424960/3166840832 (77.3%) @6.0x, remaining 1:24 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2476277760/3166840832 (78.2%) @6.0x, remaining 1:21 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2504130560/3166840832 (79.1%) @6.0x, remaining 1:18 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2531950592/3166840832 (80.0%) @6.0x, remaining 1:14 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2559803392/3166840832 (80.8%) @6.0x, remaining 1:11 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2587623424/3166840832 (81.7%) @6.0x, remaining 1:08 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2615443456/3166840832 (82.6%) @6.0x, remaining 1:05 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2643263488/3166840832 (83.5%) @6.0x, remaining 1:01 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2671083520/3166840832 (84.3%) @6.0x, remaining 0:58 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2698903552/3166840832 (85.2%) @6.0x, remaining 0:55 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2726723584/3166840832 (86.1%) @6.0x, remaining 0:51 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2754543616/3166840832 (87.0%) @6.0x, remaining 0:48 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2765881344/3166840832 (87.3%) @2.5x, remaining 0:47 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2784067584/3166840832 (87.9%) @3.9x, remaining 0:45 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2802515968/3166840832 (88.5%) @4.0x, remaining 0:43 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2820997120/3166840832 (89.1%) @4.0x, remaining 0:41 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2839445504/3166840832 (89.7%) @4.0x, remaining 0:39 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2857893888/3166840832 (90.2%) @4.0x, remaining 0:37 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2876375040/3166840832 (90.8%) @4.0x, remaining 0:35 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2894823424/3166840832 (91.4%) @4.0x, remaining 0:33 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2913304576/3166840832 (92.0%) @4.0x, remaining 0:30 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 2931752960/3166840832 (92.6%) @4.0x, remaining 0:28 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2950201344/3166840832 (93.2%) @4.0x, remaining 0:26 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2968649728/3166840832 (93.7%) @4.0x, remaining 0:24 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 2987130880/3166840832 (94.3%) @4.0x, remaining 0:22 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 3005579264/3166840832 (94.9%) @4.0x, remaining 0:19 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 3024027648/3166840832 (95.5%) @4.0x, remaining 0:17 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 3042476032/3166840832 (96.1%) @4.0x, remaining 0:15 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 3060924416/3166840832 (96.7%) @4.0x, remaining 0:13 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 3079405568/3166840832 (97.2%) @4.0x, remaining 0:10 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 3097853952/3166840832 (97.8%) @4.0x, remaining 0:08 RBU  99.9% UBU 100.0%
 3116302336/3166840832 (98.4%) @4.0x, remaining 0:06 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
 3134750720/3166840832 (99.0%) @4.0x, remaining 0:04 RBU  95.7% UBU 100.0%
 3153199104/3166840832 (99.6%) @4.0x, remaining 0:01 RBU  40.7% UBU 100.0%
builtin_dd: 1546320*2KB out @ average 5.7x1352KBps
/dev/sr0: flushing cache
/dev/sr0: closing track
/dev/sr0: closing disc
/dev/sr0: reloading tray
```

Answer (score 1):

The cdrskin run failed because you demanded -dummy with a medium
for which the drive cannot do a simulated burn run. This works only
with CD-R[W] and DVD-R[W].